# SQLPLUS output: How to automatically get minimal column width for each column?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I tried set linewidth, but that wasn't my intention,
is there anyway to shrink each columns width to the minimum that will fit the values?
or auto substring each column so that they all fit in the screen?

thanks.

Comment: you are talking about sqlplus?

Comment: @FlorinGhita yes I am :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
COLUMN columnname FORMAT An
```

for Char, VARCHAR2 (VARCHAR), LONG columns

where *n* is the the desired display width
and *columnname* is a column of a table

for example

```
COLUMN title FORMAT a40
```

For different datatype like Number and other options you can refer the below link

http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus-fmt.html

The big limitation is that you can't set an fixed width for all VARCHAR2 columns, only for specific ones.

Comment: +1 and you can just not select some columns, that ar not in your plans.

Comment: @FlorinGhita is there a way you can actually set the amount of characters that fit in the terminal width wise? because it doesn't seem to use the whole terminal?

Comment: `set linesize N` can help you, I'm not a master of sqlplus, but please analyse the [sqlplus set commands](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus-set.html)